# My Code is not working and I am not getting any error (code Shared)

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numdifftools as nd
from numpy import linalg as LA
from numpy import array

# Function definition
#function = ((x2-x1)**4)+(8*x1*x2)-x1+x2+3

def funct(x):
    return ((x[1]-x[0])**4)+(8*x[0]*x[1])-x[0]+x[1]+3

x = np.array([1.5, 1.5])  # initial Value
y=funct(x)
grad=nd.Gradient(funct)(x)
norm_grad_square=np.dot(grad,grad)
p=-grad
N=15000
epsilon = 10^(-6)
alpha_bar=5
c=0.1
rho=0.8
alpha=alpha_bar
curve_x = [x]
curve_y = [y]
i=1
while(i<=N) or (norm_grad_square>=epsilon):
    p= -grad
    misc=np.dot(grad,p)
    j=1
    while (funct(x+alpha*p)>(funct(x)+(c*alpha*misc)) or j<=1000):
        alpha_new=rho*c
        alpha=alpha_new
        j+=1
    x=x+(alpha*p)
    y=funct(x)
    grad=nd.Gradient(funct)(x)
    norm_grad_square=np.dot(grad,grad)
    curve_x.append(x)
    curve_y.append(y)
    i+=1
     
if i==N:
    print("Maximun iterations reached but convergence did not happen")
    print("x= ", x,"function= ",y,"Gradient= ",grad)
else: 
    print("x= ",x,"function= ",y,"Gradient= ",grad)
```

My code is not running and no error is shown.
I am running an algorithm to calculate an array until I reach the minimum of the function
The array contains the independent variables.
I am calculating the gradient of the function using inbuilt function.

Comment: Using a debugger or additional print statements may show more, e. g. a very long running while-loop.

Comment: Are you calling the function?

Comment: @RohithNambiar The code is a top-level script, it's not in a function.

Comment: Describe what you mean by "not working". What do you expect this to do and what does it do instead?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @Barmar oh sorry I got confused with the formatting

Comment: I'm assuming your code is getting stuck in one of the two `while` loops. You should use a debugger, such as the one in the free program [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html), to step through your code line-by-line in order to determine what the code is doing, and where its behavior diverges from your expectations. StackOverflow is not a substitute for very basic debugging that you should have done before posting here.

Answer (score 0):

You got an endless loop or [infinite loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop), right?

When symptom "infinite loop", then, as the comments suggest, debug the exit-conditions of your (while-)loops.

#### Debugging with print

For example:

1. reduce to the required variables and statements
2. then add print statements inside the loop to watch the exit-conditions

```
import numpy as np
import numdifftools as nd

def funct(x):
    return ((x[1]-x[0])**4)+(8*x[0]*x[1])-x[0]+x[1]+3

x = np.array([1.5, 1.5])  # initial Value
# ..
grad=nd.Gradient(funct)(x)
norm_grad_square=np.dot(grad,grad)   # used in exit-condition of loop
# ..
N=15000     # used in exit-condition of loop
epsilon = 10^(-6)     # used in exit-condition of loop
# ...
i=1  # used in exit-condition of loop
while(i<=N) or (norm_grad_square>=epsilon):
    print(i,N,norm_grad_square,epsilon)  # debug print
    print(f"{(i<=N)} or {(norm_grad_square>=epsilon)}")
    # remainder of your loop body: removed for simplicity
    i+=1
```

Prints an endless loop of:

```
1 15000 289.9999999999993 -16
True or True
2 15000 289.9999999999993 -16
True or True
..
15000 15000 289.9999999999993 -16
True or True
15001 15000 289.9999999999993 -16
False or True
..
356977 15000 289.9999999999993 -16
False or True
```

The ellipses shows omitted output and I interrupted the look with CTRL + C after a few seconds.

We can observe how `i` is exceeding `N` over `15000`.

#### Logical analysis

Didn't we expect to let the loop-counter variable `i` increase with each iteration and approximate to the constant maximum `N`.

Let's isolate the loop and its exit-conditions to inspect only `i`.

```
N=15000
# omitted to focus on: i, N
i=1
while(i<=N):
    # loop body
    i+=1

# end of loop
if i==N:
    print("Maximun iterations reached but convergence did not happen")

print(i, N) # debug final i compared to N
```

Does **not print** expected maximum-message but:

```
15001 15000
```

The good news is, that the loop ended with a finite `i`.
This is not `(i<=N)` and not `i==N`  but `i > N` or at least `i >= N`.

Now we could conclude: the other side  of the exit-condition (right-hand of the `or`) seems unmet or contain a bug.

#### To do

I left further debugging to you.
I would start setting `N` much lower, start with `N = 3` and slightly increase under close monitoring of the other exit-condition, e.g.

```
N = 3
i = 1
while(i<=N) or (norm_grad_square>=epsilon):
    print(i,N,norm_grad_square,epsilon)  # debug print
    # gradually insert loop-body
    i += 1
```

You can even add the statements of the loop-body gradually back to watch their evolution with each iteration and impact on the exit-condition.